# What do Java “security petititons” mean?

Tags: java, updates

I’m updating Java on a Windows 32-bit and I get a prompt that warning me about something like security petitions. The OS is in Spanish and literally says:

> Restaurar peticiones de datos de seguridad de Java.

I don’t get what is talking about. Maybe is a bad translation because in the similar English page talk about “prompts.”

http://java.com/en/download/help/restore_prompts.xml

But in the Spanish version it talk about petitions.

http://java.com/es/download/help/restore_prompts.xml

Can somebody explain me please? Petitions to who? They are talking about send data and/or request data to their servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don’t get what is talking about. Maybe is a bad translation because
>   in the similar English page talk about “prompts.”

I would say your “bad translation” assessment is correct. It seems the translation might be a bit “off” or was done by a non-native speaker. Heck, [checking with some online Spanish-to-English dictionaries](http://www.spanishcentral.com/translate/petici%C3%B3n) it seems “petición” can also be translated as “request.” Knowing that perhaps “restore requests”—instead of “petitions”—makes more sense as a translation?

Because ultimately both the [Spanish](http://java.com/es/download/help/restore_prompts.xml) and [English](http://java.com/en/download/help/restore_prompts.xml) versions of the page have the URL endpoint of `restore_prompts.xml` in them; so we can assume that they are both attempting to convey the concept of “restoring prompts.” So knowing that is the case, this English translation sums it up:

> Starting with 7u51, users are given an option to restore the security
>   prompts for any prompts that were hidden more than 30 days prior to
>   installing the latest Java release.

Basically Java just has security prompts and there is now an option—as of version 7u51—for the user decisions made when those prompts came up to be “restored” or I would better state as “forgotten” or “reset.”

If you feel this is confusing it might be worth it to contact Sun Java tech support and point out their Spanish help pages are mis-translate. Screenshots below for reference.

#### Spanish version of the page.

[image]

#### English version of the page.

[image]

Comment: My native language is Spanish and petition or request are more similar to me. Prompt make me think on system prompt "C:\". So, resuming, they are talking about some msgbox or popup warnings that ask how to proceed or request user permission to do something?